# python method overloading - multipledispatch with kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, keyword-argument, multiple-dispatch

I'm using python3.8 and [multipledispatch](https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/) library in order to overload a method signature.

multipledispatch documentation examples suggests overloading like this:

```py
from multipledispatch import dispatch


@dispatch(int, int)
def add(x, y):
    print(x + y)


@dispatch(str, str)
def add(x, y):
    print(f'{x} {y}')


add(1, 2)
add('hello', 'world')
```

but in my case I want to call add with keyword arguments like this:

```py
add(x=1, y=2)
add(x='hello', y='world')
```

and I also want to use it with default values like this:

```py
from multipledispatch import dispatch


@dispatch(int, int)
def add(x=2, y=1):
    print(x + y)


@dispatch(str, str)
def add(x='hello', y='world'):
    print(f'{x} {y}')


add(x=1)
add(y='world')
```

when trying to use it that way, dispatch decorator ignores the kwargs and throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomer/.virtualenvs/sqa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multipledispatch/dispatcher.py", line 269, in __call__
    func = self._cache[types]
KeyError: ()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomer/windows-automation-testing/sqa/try.py", line 22, in <module>
    add(x=1, y=2)
  File "/home/tomer/.virtualenvs/sqa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multipledispatch/dispatcher.py", line 273, in __call__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for add: <>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see NotImplementedError usually means that you need to subclass it and implement it. The most common situation is where you have some Abstract Class that is just an interface and you need to subclass it and implement methods that you need.

There is a placeholder for that method and just implement it.

the docs read: `Dispatches on all non-keyword arguments`

Comment: subclass what and implement what? can you give an example that will make ```add(x=1, y=2)``` this work?

Comment: You probably figured your problem already, but the multimethod package might do what you want (https://pypi.org/project/multimethod/) .